# Term for use of descriptor or noun in place of proper name?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

What is the term for the literary use of a 'descriptor' in place of a proper name, as in Shakespeare's play Much Ado about Nothing, when Benedict refers to Beatrice as "Lady Disdain" instead of Lady Beatrice?

Comment: Looks like antonomasia.

Answer (score 2):

The term *epithet* conveys your meaning.  Accoridng to [American Heritage](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/epithet)

> A term used as a descriptive substitute for the name or title of a person, such as The Great Emancipator for Abraham Lincoln.

Similarly [Compact OED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/epithet?view=uk) defines it as

> an adjective or phrase expressing a quality or attribute regarded as characteristic of the person or thing mentioned